# Show event not working on Bootstrap Collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

The "show" event doesn't appear to be working on a collapsible that is dynamically created. Multiple panels stay open when calling the javascript function. Clicking the panel headers still works fine, and if I manually click the panels first, then the "show" method appears to work. But ONLY if I click on the panel headers first. Any ideas?

JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/victoryismine06/N6rey/

```
//Click handler
$( "#btnOpen" ).click(function() {
  var idx = $("#idx").val();
    $("#accordion2 #collapse" + idx).collapse('show');    
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way.

```
$("#btnOpen").click(function () {
    var idx = $("#idx").val();
    //Just find the data-toggle element respective to the current element and invoke the click on it.
    $("#collapse" + idx).filter(':not(.in)').prev().find('[data-toggle]').trigger('click.bs.collapse.data-api');

   //or just simply do:
   // $("#accordion2").find('[data-toggle]:eq(' + idx + ')').trigger('click.bs.collapse.data-api');

   //Or you can also do:
   //$("#accordion2 .panel-collapse.in").not($("#collapse" + idx).collapse('show')).collapse('hide');
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XxZf7/)**

Reason being invocation of `collapse` method will just collapse current elements based on what type is passed, i.e hide, show or toggle. it doesnot handle the auto collapse of other open items which is handled in the custom click event attached to `[data-toggle]` elements in the collapsible. I.e in the below section:

```
$(document).on('click.bs.collapse.data-api', '[data-toggle=collapse]', function (e) {
```

So invoking a click event on the respective `data-toggle` element will handle the real collapse scenario.

Comment: Ok, I think I follow what you're saying. What I don't understand then, is why does "clicking" the panels first, "fix" the issue? If I click first, then call "show", it appears to be work. Either way, thanks for the the explanation along with your answer.

Comment: @JIsaak Even clicking on panel first has the same issue in your example. click on panel first and then click on button you will see both opened.

Comment: Try clicking on all three first. Then it's happy with the "show". Whichever panels you click on first, become "fixed" while the non-clicked ones act as if they're not part of the group.

Comment: @JIsaak That is because click event sets up the data on these collapsibles so after all click events you will have the data set on all of them from there collapse works as expected. Alternativey you can also do `  $("#accordion2 .panel-collapse.in").not($("#collapse" + idx).collapse('show')).collapse('hide');`